# Unintended change of property value with Array.from() or insertAdjacentElement

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, properties

I'm facing a problem where a property of my class gets unintentionally transformed.

```js
import { Draggable, DragTarget } from '../Models/eventlisteners';
import { HeroValues } from '../Models/responseModels';
import { Util } from './Util';

export class Heroes implements Draggable, DragTarget {
  static instance: Heroes;
  hostElement: HTMLDivElement = document.getElementById(
    'app'
  )! as HTMLDivElement;
  templateElement: HTMLTemplateElement = document.getElementById(
    'tmpl-hero-overview'
  ) as HTMLTemplateElement;
  element: HTMLCollection;

  heroes!: HeroValues;
  imagesLoaded: number = 0;

  constructor() {
    const importedNode = document.importNode(
      this.templateElement.content,
      true
    );
    this.element = importedNode.children as HTMLCollection;
  }

  async retrieveHeroes() {
    const data = await Util.getData(
      'https://api.opendota.com/api',
      '/constants/heroes'
    );
    this.heroes = data;

    for (const key in this.heroes) {
      this.heroes[data[key]['id']] = {
        img: 'https://api.opendota.com' + data[key]['img'],
        agi_gain: data[key]['agi_gain'],
        attack_range: data[key]['attack_range'],
        attack_rate: data[key]['attack_rate'],
        attack_type: data[key]['attack_type'],
        base_agi: data[key]['base_agi'],
        base_armor: data[key]['base_armor'],
        base_attack_max: data[key]['base_attack_max'],
        base_attack_min: data[key]['base_attack_min'],
        base_health: data[key]['base_health'],
        base_health_regen: data[key]['base_health_regen'],
        base_int: data[key]['base_int'],
        base_mana: data[key]['base_mana'],
        base_mana_regen: data[key]['base_mana_regen'],
        base_mr: data[key]['base_mr'],
        base_str: data[key]['base_str'],
        int_gain: data[key]['int_gain'],
        localized_name: data[key]['localized_name'],
        move_speed: data[key]['move_speed'],
        primary_attr: data[key]['primary_attr'],
        projectile_speed: data[key]['projectile_speed'],
        str_gain: data[key]['str_gain'],
        id: data[key]['id'],
      };
    }
  }

  render() {
    for (const key in this.heroes) {
      const img = document.createElement('img');
      img.id = this.heroes[key].id.toString();
      img.classList.add('hero');
      img.onerror = () => this.updateDOM();
      img.onload = () => this.updateDOM();
      img.src = this.heroes[key].img;
      this.element[0].appendChild(img);
    }
    this.configure();
  }

  dragStartHandler(event: DragEvent) {
    event.dataTransfer!.setData('text/plain', (<HTMLElement>event.target).id);
    event.dataTransfer!.effectAllowed = 'copy';
  }

  dragEndHandler(_: DragEvent) {
    console.log('dragend');
  }

  dragOverHandler(event: DragEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    (<HTMLElement>event.target).classList.add('droppable');
  }

  dragLeaveHandler(event: DragEvent) {
    (<HTMLElement>event.target).classList.remove('droppable');
  }

  dropHandler(event: DragEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const heroId = event.dataTransfer!.getData('text/plain');
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.id = this.heroes[event.dataTransfer!.getData('text/plain')]['id'];
    img.src = this.heroes[event.dataTransfer!.getData('text/plain')]['img'];
    console.log(this.element);
    if ((<HTMLElement>event.target).firstElementChild) {
      (<HTMLElement>event.target).firstElementChild?.remove();
    }
    (<HTMLElement>event.target).appendChild(img);
  }

  configure() {
    (<HTMLInputElement>this.element[0]).addEventListener(
      'dragstart',
      this.dragStartHandler.bind(this)
    );
    (<HTMLInputElement>this.element[0]).addEventListener(
      'dragend',
      this.dragEndHandler.bind(this)
    );
    (<HTMLInputElement>this.element[1].children[0]).addEventListener(
      'dragover',
      this.dragOverHandler.bind(this)
    );
    (<HTMLInputElement>this.element[1].children[0]).addEventListener(
      'dragleave',
      this.dragLeaveHandler.bind(this)
    );
    (<HTMLInputElement>this.element[1].children[0]).addEventListener(
      'drop',
      this.dropHandler.bind(this)
    );
  }

  private updateDOM() {
    this.imagesLoaded += 1;
    if (this.imagesLoaded === 121) {
      console.log(this.element);
      Array.from(this.hostElement.children).forEach((el) => {
        el.remove();
      });
      console.log(this.element);
      Array.from(this.element).forEach((el) => {
        this.hostElement.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', el);
      });
      console.log(this.element);
    }
  }

  // private function attach drag/drop listeners

  static getInstance() {
    if (this.instance) {
      return this.instance;
    }
    this.instance = new Heroes();
    return this.instance;
  }
}
```

I narrowed the problem down to this code. `this.element` is an `HTMLCollection` that I need to use at later stages again. In the first 2 console.logs, it has the expected properties, defined in the constructor beforehand. But after the second forEach-loop, it loses all of its properties and has a length of 0.

I thought maybe I need to make a copy of `this.element`, before passing it to the forEach loop. But this didn't work or I did it worng. For it I had a variable with the value `Array.from(this.element).slice()`

Then I thought maybe Array.from() transforms `this.element` unintentionally. But as of the docs it makes a copy of the initial target and doesnt transform it.

Can anyone help me out here?

Edit: I thought I don't copy my whole code since the problem seems to be pretty narrowed down. But I can provide more, if nothing's wrong in this bit.

Comment: Simply moving the element in the DOM (which you're doing) can result in it being removed from the collection - show the code where `this.element = I want to see what is here`

Comment: @Bravo thanks for answering. I pasted the whole code. this.element is defined in the constructor. It stores an HTMLCollection with 2 divs that initially comes from a Template. I use it to populate it with images from an APIRequest

Comment: well ... `importedNode.children` will change when you move children around - try `this.element = Array.from(importedNode.children)` to capture a snapshot of the children

Comment: @Bravo Great, it worked. Thank you! :) if you don't mind, can you tell me why it changes based on that? I thought since I defined these things in the constructor, everything stays static. I'm not well versed with typescript classes yet..

Comment: I explained it in my answer

Comment: Didn't see before, thanks!

Comment: Hope the explanation is enough

Comment: it gives me a good starting point. I'll read up on it.

Comment: I added some more explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
this.element = Array.from(importedNode.children)
```

so this.element is a *snapshot* of `importedNode.children` - it won't matter where the child nodes get moved

Your problem is because doing

```
Array.from(this.element).forEach....
```

doesn't stop `this.element` from still actually being `importedNode.children` - so any changes, like moving the element out of `importedNode.children` still means `this.element` won't have that element any more - since they both refer to the same object

element.children is dynamic ... if you add or remove a child, then element.children reflects the changes - clearly this is useful

setting this.element=importedNode.children doesn't make a copy, it's a *reference* to the same object

One last point

```
this.hostElement.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', el);
```

removes `el` from where it is (`importedNode.children`), and moves it to the new localtion, which would be (`this.hostElement.children`) - so this operation removes the element from `importedNode.children` and therefore `this.element`